# PHP-GD: Blur part of an image

Tags: php, php-gd

I need to blur out a part of an image.
I was able to black out a part, but instead i need to blur this.
Could somebody make an example on how to get this working?

[image: Webcam]

Answer (score 4):

You have to apply an [`image convolution`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29#Convolution)).

The matrix for blur is :

[image]

The PHP code:

```
$gaussian = array(
    array(1.0, 2.0, 1.0),
    array(2.0, 4.0, 2.0),
    array(1.0, 2.0, 1.0)
);
imageconvolution($YOUR_IMAGE, $gaussian, 16, 0); // apply convolution
```

---

A full example:

```
<?php
// Informations for blur selection
$x = 180;
$y = 20;
$width = 200;
$height = 180;

$img1 = imagecreatefromjpeg('img1.jpg'); // load source
$img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); // create img2 for selection

imagecopy($img2, $img1, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height); // copy selection to img2

$gaussian = array(
    array(1.0, 2.0, 1.0),
    array(2.0, 4.0, 2.0),
    array(1.0, 2.0, 1.0)
);
imageconvolution($img2, $gaussian, 16, 0); // apply convolution to img2

imagecopymerge($img1, $img2, $x, $y, 0, 0, $width, $height, 100); // merge img2 in img1

// Show result (img1)
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg($img1);

imagedestroy($img1);
imagedestroy($img2);
```

And don't forget to rename `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagejpeg` with the right functions if you use png or gif (see [php man](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)).

Comment: How do i do this only on one part of an image and not the whole?

Comment: You need to copy a section of your image with `imagecopy`, apply the convolution and merge images with `imagecopymerge`.

Comment: I have added a full example

Answer (score 1):

Or you can play with `imagefilter`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

```
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR)
```

Comment: The author asked for blurring parts of an image and the one you are mentioning will, in plain use, only blur the whole image. Thus it must be used in combination with other methods like Fabian Sa mentioned.